# Need help on docker scaling of micro-services

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, microservices, docker-machine

I have installed docker on an AWS linux AMI instance and built apache image from docker file. Apache image is running as a container in my instance. I would want to monitor my docker micro service and also scale them, i.e if one goes down then how to spin up other. Please help me on how to proceed with this. I am bit confused with micro-instance scaling. I tried to use cadvisor but it didnt work. **Please suggest me the other alternate to monitor and scale the docker containers**

Comment: Check out the new "service" feature built into Docker 1.12. I suspect this is what you're looking for: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/

Answer (score 2):

1. What you described is not scaling. Making sure that a container spins up in place of a failed one is more commonly referred to as fault-tolerance or auto-healing. Amazon provides a number of platforms that can accommodate those needs. The simplest ones would be Elastic Beanstalk and Elastic Container Service.
2. Scaling your applications (which includes launching new containers when the existing ones are experiencing heavy loads) is also possible through Beanstalk and Container Service, and can be costumized to scale in response to different triggers (CPU, memory, network, latency and more)

There are a few other options available for launching and managing containers - the most popular ones would be Kubernetes, DC/OS and Docker Swarm, but these might complicate things rather than simplify them - so I would suggest starting out with the AWS built in tools I've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, actually we have setup an ECS docker container and have Application manager to monitor the  docker instances. So I just wanted to know how fault tolerance work for docker instances in Application manager. If my 1 docker container in ECS goes down, then ECS will spin up other docker instance, so how Application manager would identify the other instance and start monitoring it.

Comment: Let's take it step by step, and try to use ECS lingo to make our communication clearer. ECS is running services, which in turn run tasks. When you're defining a service you are specifying the desired number of tasks. ECS will then check if you have the required amount of resources and launch the containers, monitoring their activity and launching new ones automatically in case they fail.
I don't really know which application manager are you referring to, but I don't think it is a part of the ECS architecture.

Comment: Application manager is a tool used to monitor the server status.
https://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/

and in that application manager I need to monitor the docker container to view container health and availability
https://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/help/monitors/docker-monitoring.html

and I can set it up but the point is if one docker container goes down then how would App manager discover the other container which ECS spins up automatically.

Comment: I see, I'm facing the same problem now when monitoring my services using New Relic. I don't know this product so I can't tell what solution are they offering, but moving into Docker does present some interesting monitoring challenges. I suggest checking for docker specific solutions application manager offers, or maybe contacting their support staff for help.